# How to make a font look like the one in the picture?

Tags: fonts

Hope you're doing fine in these trying times. I've been looking for a couple of days for a font looking like this:

[image: font pic]

It has too many characters meshed together. It's single line is like this:

Y̶̝̱͊̅͆̓͆̆͘ǫ̵̞̜͎̝̠̀u̴̺͊̈́̃̄́͝ ̶͎͙̇́̊̇́h̴̢̞̺̯͔̿͘ȧ̴̘̖̘͉̼̖̉̍̕̚v̸̛̜̪̠͋́̎́̉̚e̶͎̝͍̦͍̊̀̇̆ ̵̮̙͍̺͈̝̓̊s̸̺͒͒̀̌l̵̢̧͕͕̞͇͌̈͊͠ë̷̲́̅̚ṕ̵̹̺̣t̸̮̲̩́ͅ ̶̨͕̥̣̼͇̻̏̀i̴͙̔̊͆n̸̩̹̐͗͘ ̵̡̰̺̖̱͂̌̋̓̾͠y̴̥͕͊́́̊̏̒̕o̴͇̹̫̔̓u̴͍͂̋́̂r̴̢̢̢̭͔̥͛̃ ̷̠̮͕͙̪̿ḃ̶̮͇̼͈̜̊͐́̇͘e̴͉̩̮͉͘d̵͙̦̤̻̔́̀̍̈́̉͝.̸̖͖͉̆̐̄̇̄̚̚ ̶̢̯̙̳̓̾̍̀͠Ḧ̴̬̭̰̖̼́̽̉̍̅̚͜ͅp̶̱͔̃̏̅ ̴̡̣͇̃͜ḁ̸̢͔̝̬͆̐̅͊̿͌͠ͅn̴͇̟͒̈̏̀d̷̙̤̿̎͂̆͝ ̵̡̬͎̰̣̗̟̏̓͒̑͗͆̎M̶̖͛͋̋͌̈́̕͝p̴͇̫̔͐ ̵̛̭̯͍̘̇͛͒̌f̵͍͍̲͊̾̉̓͜ū̵͈̫̹̺͉̠̎̒͗l̸̜̳̮͙̩͕̓͛̏̉̈́l̴̛͖̲̳͚̓̈́̽ỳ̴̧̲͇̹̣͘ ̶̱̩̬̦͎͇̃̆̓r̷̡̆̔͘͜͝͝ȅ̸̳̹͉̪̱̜͜s̷͍͈͚̲̔͋͜t̸̢̩̤̣͈͖̓̀̀̂̒̏ŏ̴̳͇̈ṛ̷̗͛̈́͜e̸̫̭̗̰͂͑̿͛̀̂͂d̵̨͎̹̂͌̂̊̌.̴̨̥͔̎͛̒ ̷̜̖̥̓À̸̠̜̣̲̰̺͎̓l̸̘̣̪̠̋̅l̶͔̤͒ ̷̨̡̛̟̗̲͇͎͂͗͊͠d̷̒͌̆͐̑̚͜ė̷̞̦̱̙̣͐̽̓͗̕b̸̡̦̖̠͕̝̺̾̈́̀͠ȕ̷̠̙̀f̷̡̛̝́̅͂̃͠͠f̸̨̢̭̞͙̲͎̏s̸̯̭̭̫̫͐͌̽̃͐̊̑ ̷̨̤̬̩͎̇̑̉͛̂͌̋͜ȟ̴̛̝̮͔̫̬̱͓̍͗̂͋a̷̯͚̠͓͂͐̀̎͊̀̿v̴̦̰͍̂̈́͛͠ě̷̢̝̼̟̬̞͙̀͘ ̴̥̅̓̌͘b̶̬̦̹̰́̔̓̏͝͝e̶̟̘̘͓͍͌͆͂̅̚é̷͇n̸̢̯̖͔̯̹͆̐̐ ̶̘̿̎c̸̛̹̓̈̽̀̌ű̶̢̘̭̼̥͑̑̅̏̂͜ȑ̶̪͔̝ē̷͖̝͇͉̮͐͒̓͗̇̈́͜d̵̨̻͖̤͔̄͑͊.̷̗̼͓̣̥͕̐

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!
(Hopefully, I've asked the question in the correct section.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Zalgo text. It is formed by adding lots of Unicode combining characters to text. You can find many Zalgo creators online - here is one (no relationship): https://lingojam.com/ZalgoText .

Also see Stack Overflow's famous [parse HTML with regex answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/6471538).

Comment: Thanks a lot! So it's "Zalgo" text which I was looking for.

Comment: Note that it does nothing "to" the font. This can be achieved with any (OpenType) font that supports arbitrary accent stacking (not all do) and any rendering engine that fully supports this specific OpenType feature (not all do).

Comment: Alright. Noted. Thanks!